# How to handle "flat" relative imports in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

Since there are so many questions on relative imports, I will make it as short and sweet as possible. And yes, I've read "[*Relative imports for the billionth time*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)".

I have a project structure like this:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── model
    │   └── train_model.py
    └── preprocessing
        └── process.py
```

where I want to be able to, as an example, call `make preprocessing`or `make train` which then runs either `process.py`or `train_model.py` with

```
## Make train
train:
    python3 src/model/train_model.py
```

E.g. modules will always from the top project folder where the Makefile lives.

Now, my problem is that i might have dependencies between different submodules, such as `train_model.py` and `process.py`. Specifically, if I try to import `process`in `train_model` by using `from src.preprocessing import process` i get an error `ImportError: No module named 'src'`. In a similar vein, I've tried `from ...preprocessing import process`, which gives me another error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`.

I use `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the end of my `train_model.py`, but I can't seem to figure out, how python uses `__name__`to find different modules, and if this f**** something up in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PYTHONPATH`.  I would do it this way:

Makefile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(abspath src)

train:
    python3 src/model/train_model.py
```

train_model.py:

```
from preprocessing import process
```

Now every import will first look under `src`.  It is not conventional to write `from src.preprocessing import process` - typically imports are understood to be within some base directory (you wouldn't want to set `PYTHONPATH` to the directory above `src`, because it may contain things you don't want to import).

Comment: Hi John, and thanks for the answer. The first bit with exporting the pythonpath in the makefile works perfectly. However, the import `from preprocessing import process` does not work. I simply get `ImportError: No module named 'preprocessing`. Any ideas?

Comment: @TMorville: What does `print(sys.path)` tell you if you put it in `train_model.py`?  How about `print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))`?

Comment: `print(sys.path)` outputs (amongst others) `/src/model` and not just `/src/`as I am guessed it is supposed to do. When calling `make train` the output from `print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))` is blank. When calling directly with `python3 src/model/train_model.py` it is `None`.

Comment: @TMorville: OK so somehow the environment variable is not being set.  Try putting `PYTHONPATH=src python3 src/model/train_model.py` in your Makefile....

Comment: Adding the new path works, putting in `'/src python3 src/model/train_model.py'` in `sys.path`. I am guessing that `PYTHONPATH=src python3 src/model/train_model.py`was a mistake? If I simply add `export PYTHONPATH=src` then `project/src` gets added to PYTHONPATH correctly, and now it seems to work!